# What does lint_control_click_version_up_to_date mean?

Tags: application-development

I submitted an app to the store and it gets rejected with this message:-

```
lint_control_click_version_up_to_date
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the version of click you are currently running is too old. If you run a supported release and have the SDK PPA enabled, you should generally be fine. Find out how to do that here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/